# Excel formulae for max or min of multiple occurrences of vlookup

Tags: excel

I need to do a complicated vlookup/maxif type of selection. The data I have is as below

```
Row Col G    Col H   Col I   colJ        col K
1    Bench  Strip   Block   BenchAbove   BenchBelow
2    1       1       4
3    1       1       5
4    1       1       6
5    1       1       7
6    1       1       8
7    8       1       4         ??           ??
8    8       1       5
9    8       1       6
10   8       1       7
11   8       1       8
12   9       1       4
13   9       1       5
14   9       1       6
15   9       1       7
```

.....this list is long ( this is a sample only)

For every combination of (Strip, block) like say (1,4) There are benches like 1, 8 and 9. So bench above for 8 is 1 and bench below for 8 is 9. I need to determine the bench above and bench below for each row. There are no bench above 1 and no bench below 9.

I dont think vlookup is the solution here. Not sure if MAX(IF..) can help either. What would be the best formulae to obtain say on row 7, block combination is 1,4. The bench in question is 8. The bench above is 1 and bench below is 9. So 2 formulae will be required on Col J and Col I above.

The expected answer for the above sample data is :

```
Row Col G    Col H   Col I   colJ        col K
1    Bench  Strip   Block   BenchAbove   BenchBelow
2    1       1       4      -             8 
3    1       1       5      -             8
4    1       1       6      -             8
5    1       1       7      -             8
6    1       1       8      -             8
7    8       1       4      1             9
8    8       1       5      1             9 
9    8       1       6      1             9
10   8       1       7      1             9
11   8       1       8      1             9
12   9       1       4      8             -
13   9       1       5      8             -
14   9       1       6      8             -
15   9       1       7      8             -
```

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: Using Excel 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in `J2`:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((H$1:H1=H2)*(I$1:I1=I2)),G$1:G1),"-")
```

In `K2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G3:G$16,MATCH(1,INDEX((H3:H$16=H2)*(I3:I$16=I2),),0)),"-")
```

[image]

However, I find your question a bit confusing so this answer might be a bit off.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer, but it did not work. I find that you are not using Col H and Col I in your formulae..Is it possible to include them ? . I am looking for the next (higher, and lower) Col G for every set of I,J combination. For example (1,4) is a combination. Other combinations could be (1,5), (1,6) etc in the data I have given. I have several other rows in the real data. So if you were to filter in excel for Col H = 1 and Col I = 4 you will get in Col G the following 1,8,9.  Hence position of row wise above 8 is 1, and below 8 is 9. It does not have to do with +1 or -1. Thank you

Comment: @Ranajit, I edited my answer as it's a little clearer now. See if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the edited response, It worked  perfectly. Except for the last row- but that is OK I can manage it manually . Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Ranajit, see how I in my example refered to row ***16*** instead of ***15*** to make that work? Also, if it answered your question please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Office365` then you can use `MAXIFS(), MINIFS()` easily to get `BenchAbove` and `BenchBelow`. Try-

```
=MAXIFS(A2:A15,B2:B15,B7,C2:C15,C7)
=MINIFS(A2:A15,B2:B15,B7,C2:C15,C7)
```

[image]

> ***EDIT: Solution for Excel-2016***

Try below formula-

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$15,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$2:$A$15)-ROW($A$1)/(($B$2:$B$15=B7)*($C$2:$C$15=C7)),ROW(1:1)))
=INDEX($A$2:$A$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$15)-ROW($A$1)/(($B$2:$B$15=B7)*($C$2:$C$15=C7)),ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harun for your prompt response. I am on Excel 2016, tried the formulae but it did not work, I get #NAME? . Is there an equivalent in Excel 2016

Comment: Thank you Harun for the modified response. Sorry I am not getting the desired answer. I tried =INDEX($G$2:$G$30000,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($G$2:$G$30000)-ROW($A$1)/(($H$2:$H$30000=H2)*($I$2:$I$30000=I2)),ROW(1:1)))                                                          My data for Bench is Col G, Strip on Col H and Block on Col I. Did I get it right ?

Comment: Sorry I might not have clarified it in the question, I need the BenchAbove and BenchBelow for each and every row , not only for row 7. Only that for Bench 1 the bench above is not there, and for bench 9 - a bench below is not there

Comment: @Ranajit Just you adjust the formula like `=INDEX($G$2:$G$30000,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($G$2:$G$30000)-ROW($A$1)/(($H$2:$H$30000=H2)*($I$2:$I$30000=I2)),ROW($1:$1)))`

Comment: With this change I have all rows with the same answer or 9 and 1.

Comment: @Ranajit Can you please clarify what will be output for each row then for your given sample data?

Comment: Thank you. I have added the expected answer in the question above